# @ManyToMany/@OneToMany mappedby attribute for bidirectional association

Tags: java, annotations, jpa-2.0

I'm working on a JPA Compliancy kit for my internship... Part of that kit involves testing correct implementation of corner cases.

`@ManyToMany` has a mappedBy attribute. JPA states that:

> String mappedBy - The field or property that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

No default is given - the default column is empty.

Given a bidirectional `@ManyToMany` - this example is from the JPA 2.0 JSR-317 specification itself!

**Customer**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="CUST_PHONES")
public Set<PhoneNumber> getPhones() { return phones; }
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="phones")
public Set<Customer> getCustomers() { return customers; }
```

The mappedBy attribute hasn't been defined in the `@ManyToMany` of `Customer`! Is there a default for bidirectional mappings that I'm not aware of, or what?

I looked at similar cases and found:
`@OneToOne` - mappedBy is optional, no default
`@OneToMany` - exactly the same as `@ManyToMany` (mappedBy is optional for bidirectional, with no default)

**In short, my question:**
For `@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany`, what should be placed in the mappedBy attribute for the owning side of the relationship (`Customer` in example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from being a corner case. Every bidirectional association has an owner side and an inverse side.

JPA uses the owning side to decide if an association exists between two entities. The other side is ignored.

The owning side is the one which defines how the association is mapped (using the JoinColumn, JoinTable, etc. annotations). It doesn't have any `mappedBy` attribute.

The inverse side uses the `mappedBy` attribute to say: "Hey, I'm just the inverse association of the one mapped by the following property".

So, by definition, the owning side doesn't have a `mappedBy` attribute. If it had one, it wouldn't be the owning side.

This is well explained in the [JPA spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html). If you need to build a compliancy kit for this specification, you'd better read and understand it.

I don't really see the point of writing such a compliancy kit since, as written on the [JPA2 JSR home page](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317),

> As required by the Java Specification Participation Agreement (JSPA),
>   the Java Persistence API, version 2.0 TCK will be licensed at no
>   charge without support to qualified not-for-profit entities. Such
>   qualification will be verified by the Compatibility Testing
>   Scholarship Program. Support may also be provided at no charge with
>   approval of the scholarship board. For more information, please refer
>   to: http://java.sun.com/scholarship/.

Comment: The compliancy kit is just a fancy name for unit tests for the annotations used by JPA. Right now the focus is on ORM... are you saying these unit-tests (or something else along those lines) already exist? The company I'm having my internship for wants me to develop this as part of testing their open-source application.

I kinda understand the usage of `mappedBy`, I'm just confused as to its exact wording. Why does it say that the mappedBy annotation is required for non-unidirectional relationships without excluding the owning side of a bidirectional relationship?

Comment: The TCK is used to test a JPA implementation. It's not used to test an application built with JPA. So I guess your kit could be useful, then. It probably says it like that because the developer was lazy, and thought the users of the annotation would read the JPA spec, or the javadoc of the annotation itself, where the use of the mappedBy attribute is explained in details.

Comment: "where the use of the mappedBy attribute is explained in details." Could you give me a link to this documentation? I can find some of it online, but it seems to parrot what I can read in the JSR-317 spec... and doesn't shed any light on this particular situation.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html: *If the association is bidirectional, either side may be designated as the owning side. If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the ManyToMany annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.* And a code example follows.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer, and put down that whilst it's not explicitly stated that the owning side of the relationship isn't allowed to have the mappedBy attribute, trying to add it would break other conditions and is thus not allowed.